# How to rebuild /etc/cron.d on CentOS?

Tags: centos, cron, symlink, rpm

I installed an RPM on a CentOS machine that was supposed to merge its own files contained in a `/etc/cron.d` structure with the current `/etc/cron.d`. However it replaced the current contents. I believe `cron.d` is a symlink.

How can I retrieve the original `/etc/cron.d`?

Comment: Are you sure?  Even if the directory was a symlink, it would have to *intentionally delete* things to do this, which would be pretty weird.

Comment: How was the directory `/etc/cron.d` a symlink? It was a link to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/cron.d` is not a symlink on my CentOS 5.x box:

```
 drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Feb  5  2013 /etc/cron.d
```

So, if it's missing entirely, you can restore it with:

```
# install -d -m 700 -o root -g root /etc/cron.d
```

If something else is in its place, you could move it out of the way, recreate the directory, and then selectively move things back in place.

To get a list of all files that are *supposed* to be installed there, say:

```
# rpm -qla | grep /etc/cron.d
```

Saying `rpm -qf filename` will tell you which package owns that file, hence which package you can reinstall to restore that file.